# How to enable store view option with collection using custom module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento, I have searched everywhere but i didnt get any sufficient criteria for this task. I got  project in Magento in which there is a custom module enables us to add experts of the site. but when I try to add a new expert I dont see store view option there. How can I display that option while adding an expert.

My requirement is to show content based on current store view but the field to select store view on add/edit page is missing while other custom modules have this option enabled. as the project is live I don't want to try some random code that may effect any other section.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us some code you've already written? Where is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId($myStoreId);
```

Where `Mage::app()->getStore->getStoreId();` will be your store id.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. But I have updated the question, Please read it once again. :)

Comment: May be you are looking for this. http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-adding-store-view-selection-to-your-modules-adminhtml/